# zsh history; track git branch name along with history?

Tags: zsh

When I cat my zsh history, I see the timestamp along with the command executed.  Is there any way to have zsh record the git branch that was checked out for the active terminal session tab at the time the command was executed?

Answer (score 0):

Define a `zshaddhistory` function which determines the git branch name and appends that...

```
function zshaddhistory() {
    GIT_BRANCH=` git rev-parse --abbrev-ref=strict HEAD 2>/dev/null `
    print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'} ### ${GIT_BRANCH} ${PWD} $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %R')"
    return 1
   }
```